# Count by rows and display result in coulmn

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a data  which have EMAIL_ADDRESS and languages. I want to count the email address by language and then display the result in a one single row

```
CHINESE     PORTUGUESE    KOREAN SPANISH FRENCH  
  2             1          1      1      1
```

WHEN I tried using case statement

```
select         

  (case when  (LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE') THEN count(distinct email_address) END) as CHINESE,    
 (case when  (LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH') THEN count(distinct email_address) END) as FRENCH,   
(case when  (LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE') THEN count(distinct email_address) END) as PORTUGUESE,       
  (case when  (LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH') THEN count(distinct email_address) END) as SPANISH,    
  (case when  (LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN') THEN count(distinct email_address) END) as KOREAN    


from     
 table1  
group by language;
```

Here is what I do not want

```
CHINESE  PORTUGUESE  KOREAN  SPANISH FRENCH  
  2         0          0      0     0  
  0         1          0      0     0  
  0         0          1      0     0  
  0         0          0      1     0  
  0         0          0      0     1
```

It should be in one line 5 columns without zero

Answer (score 2):

You need to sum those `CASE` expressions, and also there doesn't appear to be any need to use `GROUP BY`, if you just want a table-level aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address END) AS CHINESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address END) AS FRENCH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address END) AS PORTUGUESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address END) AS SPANISH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address END) AS KOREAN
FROM table1;
```

If you instead wanted to do these aggregations by something more granular, e.g. a user, then `GROUP BY` the user column and also select it:

```
SELECT
    userId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN email_address END) AS CHINESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN email_address END) AS FRENCH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN email_address END) AS PORTUGUESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN email_address END) AS SPANISH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN email_address END) AS KOREAN
FROM table1
GROUP BY
    userId;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim..I was using the count distinct inside that's why i need the group by

Comment: You don't need `GROUP BY` to use count distinct :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I would recommend doing the `distinct` first:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'CHINESE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHINESE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FRENCH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'PORTUGUESE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PORTUGUESE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SPANISH,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LANGUAGE = 'KOREAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS KOREAN
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT email_address, language
      FROM table1
     ) t1;
```

On a larger table, it would be interesting to compare the performance of the two methods.  But I would expect one `DISTINCT` to be faster than five.